# Is Special Research the only way to obtain Mew?

Tags: pokemon-go

Niantic doesn't specifically say whether Special Research is the only way to obtain Mew. Although we assume it is, is there any confirmation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While there hasn't been anything officially *announced* on the subject, it is safe to say that the current line of Special Research - "A Mythical Discovery" is the *only* way to obtain Mew.

For inference:

- Mew is not an EX-Raid boss.
- Unlike Unown, who appears in the wild ***very*** rarely, Mew absolutely does not spawn.
- Mew has not been encountered in any conceivable fashion before this release - wild spawns as mentioned or raid battles.
- Legendary and rare/desirable Pokemon have been withheld for release despite their existence in the actual game code for special events before - notably, the Legendary Raids can still accommodate Articuno to this day, but at the time of writing, it hasn't been in a raid since [its first rotation](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/legendaryrewards/).